# captcha in rails 1.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working with a very old rails application (v1.2.6) and need to implement a captcha on the site. Does anyone know what approach I can take to do this?

**I have tried:**

- Searching for rails plugins that support v1.2.6 (found nothing)
- Setting up `simple-captcha` plugin (but only works on
  rails > 3)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Rails 1.2 has no usable plugin mechanism built-in (and it's **really** old). I guess the only usable way forward is to read the source of other plugins and scrape the stuff you need off of it and include it into your app. You'll probably need working knowledge of both Rails 3 plugins (or whatever your source plugin is targeted at) and Rails 1.2. Finally, I'm really sorry for you...

Comment: Hmmm. So I guess I am out of luck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up implementing reCaptcha [Non-JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#Standard) as suggested by Javier.

Added the following in my **view**:

```
<p class="text-black-11px-17px" style="color: red;"><%=flash[:captcha_error]%></p> 
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=PUBLIC_KEY_HERE"></script>
<noscript>
   <iframe
src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=PUBLIC_KEY_HERE"
       height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
   <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">
   </textarea>
   <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field"
       value="manual_challenge">
</noscript>
```

Added the following in my **controller**:

```
# verify reCaptcha
uri = URI.parse("http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify")
response = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, {
  "privatekey" => "PRIVATE_KEY_HERE", 
  "remoteip" => request.env['REMOTE_ADDR'], 
  "challenge" => params[:recaptcha_challenge_field], 
  "response" => params[:recaptcha_response_field]
})

flash[:captcha_error] = nil
if ((@contact.valid?) && (response.body.include? "success")) 
    # VALIDATION SUCCESSFUL - SEND THE EMAIL
elsif (response.body.include? "false")
   flash[:captcha_error] = "The CAPTCHA you entered is invalid. Please try again."
   render :action => 'contact'        
else
    render :action => 'contact'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use a plugin, is recommendable to use when they are available, but is not a mandatory thing. 
Probably the "Do-it yourself" installation needs more steps but definitely will works.
Take a look for example at the [reCAPTCHA documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display), there is a complete section dedicated to explain the use of the library without plugins.

Basically there are two approaches:

1. The Standard Challenge and Non-JavaScript API.
2. The reCAPTCHA AJAX API

With any of those ways, depends of your needs, hopefully you should have captcha working in a lot of scenarios without troubles. The API is well explained and have a few examples.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But what happens if Javascript is disabled and the form is submitted?

Comment: That's covered in the first approach "Non-JavaScript API". The example shows that if javascript is disabled, then an iframe is loaded, and everything works as expected.